# Search for a value with a wildcard in a column with a specific pattern in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this function:

```
flag = (df['VALUE'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False)
```

In my column VALUE, I have values like **"AAAA", "BBBB", "ABAB", "BABA", "CAAB"**

Now I want to use my function to search for something like **"**AB"**, so my function returns "ABAB" and "CAAB". How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [`str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
df['VALUE'].str.endswith('AB')
```

Comment: Hey Yatu - thank you. Maybe I was too specific with my question. The idea is to generally use placeholder in a string

Comment: In such case, if that's not what you want though it indeed answers your question as currently is, I'd kindly encourage you to ask the question anew in a separate post made clearer this time. Otherwise it seems as I've not answered your question (after the edits), thanks @JohnDole